# Qt: How to correctly use moveToThread(this)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a class like this:

```
class myClass:public QThread
```

then in its constructor I did:

```
myClass::myClass(){
    moveToThread(this);
    ...
}
```

It seems that all the member slots are actually working on the worker thread.
But how could I stop the thread during the deconstruction in this case?

Comment: Have a look here: http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/

Answer (score 9):

Simply don't do threading like that.

The proper way to use `moveToThread()` is described in Qt docs:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork(const QString &parameter) {
        QString result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result);
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &result);
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &);
signals:
    void operate(const QString &);
};
```

or by inheriting `QThread`, like:

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        QString result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result);
    }
signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &s);
};

void MyObject::startWorkInAThread()
{
    WorkerThread *workerThread = new WorkerThread(this);
    connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::resultReady, this, &MyObject::handleResults);
    connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
    workerThread->start();
}
```

but not both of them at the same time.
More on that topic [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qthread.html#details)